# How to learn a hidden model variable (task variance) in tensorflow that has no ground truth data

Tags: python, tensorflow, faster-rcnn

I am working with a faster-rcnn type of system where `automated focal loss` was recently implemented from https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.09048.pdf

In the above-linked paper in section `3.4. Regression` it states

> We assume that the labels are distributed around the actual correct ground truth by a Gaussian distribution with a variance of σ^2.

and

> However, to correctly compute the cumulative distribution function the variance σ^2 of the task needs to be estimated. [...] training the variable σ^2 like a weight of the network.

I do not have data for the task variance `σ^2`.

I do not fully understand how it can be learned without having data for it.

Should I simply make the variable `trainable` and assume that the optimize knows what to do?